# How to sort <li> elements inside <ul> with JavaScript (bubble sort)?

Tags: javascript, html

I have 3

elements inside :

```
<ul id = "friends">
            
    <li>Zvonar</li>
    <li>Ivan</li>
    <li>Petro</li>

</ul>
```

And JS code:

```
let list = document.getElementsByTagName('li');

                
for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {

    for (let j = 0; j < list.length; j++) {

        if (list[j].textContent > list[j + 1].textContent) {

            buf = list[j].textContent;
            list[j] = list[j + 1].textContent;
            list[j + 1] = buf;
        }
    }
}
```

But it gives me an error that [j + 1] is undefined, at the fourth string.

Is there any way to sort them using JavaScipt?
Will be thankful for any answer.

Comment: Use `let i = 0; i < list.length - 1; i++` and `let j = i + 1; j < list.length; j++`. Now compare (and potentially swap) `[i]` and `[j]`. (JS also has `Array.sort`)

Answer (score 1):

You are referencing an array index that does not exist. The list goes from index 0-2, so on the last iteration the if statement will break because you are doing 2+1 = list[3]. But the array does not have that index. Since it's the last index of the array, and that index has already been checked against the n-1 index, there is no reason to check it. So I think you can change your loop to be:

```
for (let j = 0; j < list.length-1; j++) {...
```

I have not tested this, but I think this will solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

When you are on the last index you add one to get the next and there is nothing there.

Personally I would not swap the text around. I would pass in an array of the elements.

```js
const bubbleSortText = function(arr) {
  const len = arr.length;
  for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < len - 1; j++) {
      if (arr[j].innerText.localeCompare(arr[j + 1].innerText) === 1) {
        const tmp = arr[j];
        arr[j] = arr[j + 1];
        arr[j + 1] = tmp;
      }
    }
  }
  return arr;
};

const ul = document.querySelector('#friends');
const lis = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('#friends li'));
const newOrder = bubbleSortText(lis);
newOrder.forEach(function (li) {
  ul.appendChild(li);
});
```

```html
<ul id="friends">
  <li>Zvonar</li>
  <li>Ivan</li>
  <li>Petro</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
let list = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
let arr = Array.from(list);
arr.sort((a, b) => a.innerText > b.innerText ? 1 : a.innerText < b.innerText ? -1 : 0)
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but a _possible_ motivation of the downvoter was:  this solution will sort the list, but won't re-order the elements in the DOM (nor their contents), and of course won't change the display of the HTML ;)